# Meu arquivo js não está carregando

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Estudando Ajax com JQuery, no livro do Mauricio Samy Silva não está funcionando comigo. Fiz um arquivo js fora e agora eu não consigo carregá-lo. O que fiz acho não está errado. Debuguei o browser com F12 e não vejo nenhum erro de js. Coloquei vários alerts e não disparou nenhum. Abaixo me js e na sequencia meu html. Usei o próprio template do VS2013.

```
function iniciaAjax() {

    var objAjax = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        objAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){

        try
        {
            objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (ex)
            {
                objAjax = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function requisitar(arquivo){

    var requisicaoAjax = iniciaAjax();
    if (requisicaoAjax) {
        alert(1);

        requisicaoAjax.onreadystateshange = function () {
            alert(2);
            mostraResposta(requisicaoAjax);
            alert(3);
            requisicaoAjax.open("GET", arquivo, true);
            requisicaoAjax.send(null);
            alert(4);
        }
    }
}

function mostraResposta(requisicaoAjax) {
alert(11);

    if (requisicaoAjax.readyState == 4) {
alert(21);
        if (requisicaoAjax.status == 200 || requisicaoAjax.status == 304) {

            alert("Problema com o servidor");

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Problema com o servidor");
        }
    }
}
```

Eveja como está meu Html. O arquivo acima(js) coloquei dentro de um arquivo chamado `libAjax`, conforme está no meu html.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Teste_Javascript._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script src="Scripts/Ajax/libAjax.js"></script>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    <a href="Content/mensagem.txt" onclick="requisitar(this.href); return false;">Resultado aqui</a>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model.
            A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301948">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
            <p>
                NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301949">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
            <p>
                You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301950">Learn more &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com outros erros que encontrei :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que identifiquei seu problema, você não está retornando o `objAjax` na função de `iniciaAjax()`, faça:

```
function iniciaAjax() {

    var objAjax = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        objAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){

        try
        {
            objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (ex)
            {
                objAjax = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return objAjax; /* aqui */
}
```

Descobri 2 erros na sua função requisitar, estava escrito `onreadystateshange` ao invés de `onreadystatechange` e a chamada da requisição tava dentro da função.

```
function requisitar(arquivo){

    var requisicaoAjax = iniciaAjax();
    if (requisicaoAjax) {
        alert(1);

        requisicaoAjax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            alert(3);
            mostraResposta(requisicaoAjax);
            alert(4);
        }
        // isso fica fora do onreadystatechange
        requisicaoAjax.open("GET", arquivo, true);
        requisicaoAjax.send();
        alert(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não. O primeiro alert foi disparado, mas os demais não, ou seja, ele validou a função com True e depois acho que ele sai do escopo. Com F12 não vejo nenhum erro.

Comment: @pnet Atualizei a resposta com outros 2 erros que encontrei na sua função.

Comment: Não entra nesse bloco: requisicaoAjax.onreadystateshange = function () {
            alert(2);
            mostraResposta(requisicaoAjax);
            alert(3);
            
        }

Comment: @pnet Como eu te disse você está escrevendo `shange` ao invés de `change`, dessa forma ele nunca vai chamar.

Comment: Cara, nem me atentei a isso. Resolvido. Vou marcar sua resposta.

Comment: @pnet Bom estudo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Importe o javascript dessa maneira:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Ajax/libAjax.js") %>'></script>
```

Comment: Onde está o diretório Scripts na árvore de diretórios da sua aplicação? Na raiz?

Comment: sim, essa seria o meu caminho. Projetos/Teste_Javascript/ScriptsAjax<libAjax.js

Comment: Essa linha está correta para chamar a função js? <a href="Content/mensagem.txt" onclick="requisitar(this.href); return false;">Resultado aqui</a>